# iTextSharp angle of text

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf, itext, italic

I have a little problem with my application.
I want to add a text to a PDF but with a little special thing.
The text has to be italic, but the angle of italic is too high!
Italic has a angle of 11 degrees but I need 10 degrees!

I don't know how itextsharp works, if there is a function which creates a new italic function which is another like Visual Studio uses. 
Then I could edit the library, but I don't know how.

Or is there a possibility to create my own function which does what I want?

I don't need a rotation I need a angle like italic.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: How do you request italics in iTextSharp? Do you use an actual italic font or do you employ poor man's italics?  (If you're not sure, show appropriate code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method you can call on Chunk that does this for you.

```
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Hello world",  
                        FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 
                                            20, 
                                            Font.NORMAL, 
                                            new BaseColor(255, 0, 0)));  
chunk.setSkew(0, 25);
document.add(chunk);
```

The method setSkew does all the magic here.

For more details, check out http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-3

It also shows examples of using this method.

Comment: Thanks for the help, thought it would be more work ^^